# Counting the Elements in Set J: A Problem Involving Prime Numbers and Matrices

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

consider a prime number, denoted as 'p,' and a set J consisting of all 2 × 2 matrices:
J = {
[a b],
[c d]
},
where the elements a, b, c, and d are selected from the set {0, 1, 2, ..., p − 1}. These matrices in set J must satisfy two conditions: a + d ≡ 1 (mod p) and ad − bc ≡ 0 (mod p). Our task is to determine the number of elements in set J.

Here is where I have currently solved:

since a + d ≡ 1 (mod p) and ad − bc ≡ 0 (mod p) then we have a ≡ 1-d (mod p) and ad − bc ≡ 0 (mod p) implies (1-d)d≡bc (mod p)

If both a and b are 0, then regardless of the values of c and d, ad - bc ≡ 0 (mod p)  There are p^2 cases

If both a and b are not 0, for every pair of distinct values for a and b, there exists a unique pair of values for c and d that satisfies ad - bc ≡ 0 (mod p). Considering there are (p-1) * p possible choices for a and b, there are (p-1) * p cases

Next, I am unsure of how to proceed with the discussion, and I am uncertain if my current progress is correct.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started well, since $a+d = 1$ then every choice for $d$ uniquely determines $a =1-d \mod(p) \in \left \{ 0,...,p-1  \right \}  $. So we need to count how many options are there to solve $(1-d)d = bc \mod(p)$.

If $d= 1,0$ then we get $bc = 0 \mod(p)$ so either $(b=0 , c\neq 0)$ or  $(b\neq0 , c= 0)$ or $(b=0 , c=0)$  [all mod(p)]. Giving us $(p-1) +(p-1)+1 = 2p-1$ possible choices, and in total $2(2p-1)$ options for $J$.

However, if $d \neq 0,1$ then $d(1-d) \neq 0 \mod(p)$ - or in other words $d(1-d) \in \mathbb{Z_p}^*$ (i.e. the multiplicative group of inverse elements mod p - which are exaclty {1,...,p-1}). Therefore, the mapping $x\to d(1-d)x$ is an isomorphism of  $\mathbb{Z_p}^*$ and so the number of solutions of  $(1-d)d = bc \mod(p)$ is the same as  $1 = bc \mod(p)$ which is exactly $p-1$ (as for any choice of $b$ there is a unique inverse $c$). Thus we found $(p-2)(p-1)$ options for $J$,

In total there are $2(2p-1) + (p-2)(p-1) = p(p+1)$ options for $J$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to ask a question: In the case where d ≠ 0, 1, are we not considering the possibility of exchanging b and c?

Comment: we do - note that we choose b to be any non zero element, and c to be its inverse (mod p). in particular for every choice $(b , b^{-1})$ of a solution $(b^{-1} , b)$ is also one.